Anime where they use drops or orbs to fight, like Candy Crush
Anime where they use drops or orbs to fight. They play something like Candy Crush, and they summon beats to fight. Main character had red hair/brown hair (Goku style).

Hi and welcome to SFF.SE! Take a look at this advice on a good identification question and see if you can add some detail - for example, when was "when I was child"? Where did you watch it? What do you mean when you say they played Candy Crush?

I presume you meant "summon beasts". I can't think of any music-based fighting in anime, although that would actually be pretty cool
